# Timezone conversation

Tags: oracle, timezone

I'm not too well versed in working with Timezones.  So, forgive me if this is a rather rhetorical question.

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT CAST(TO_DATE('05182021221504','MMDDYYYYHH24MISS') AS TIMESTAMP)
         AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
FROM   dual;
```

Why is my result 5/19?   5/19/2021 3:15:04.000000 AM +00:00

The time is clearly 10:15:04 PM  (22:15:04), with a 5/18 date.   Why does this roll it into some 5/19 day / time?

Comment: "The time is clearly 10:15:04 PM" - in what timezone?

Comment: Timezone:   CST, assume that is what you are referring to.

Comment: Are you sure your session time zone isn't US Eastern time (`America/New_York`)?  The values you gave indicate a UTC-4 offset, which aligns with EDT on that date (among others).

Comment: Also you might want to read [these docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-D8C7A7EB-A507-42A2-9B10-5301E822A7F2).  Pay attention to the `FROM_TZ` usage in the example.

Comment: 23:15 is 11pm btw, not 10pm. 11pm New York is somewhere around 3am UTC (the next calendar day).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "conversion" (not "conversation")?

Anyway - it seems that you input a string representing a date-time without time zone, and you want to convert to a timestamp with time zone, assuming the time zone to be UTC. Right so far?

If so, you are using the wrong function. You need `from_tz`, something like

```
select from_tz(to_timestamp('05182021221504','MMDDYYYYHH24MISS'), 'UTC')
from   dual;
```

Now, if you want to understand what happens with your attempt: `at time zone` converts from one time zone to another. Your input doesn't have a time zone, it is just an abstract timestamp. Instead of throwing an error, Oracle uses a default - your session's time zone. So it converts the date and time from CDT to UTC, resulting in a different date and time-of-day. If you look at the time difference, keep in mind that UTC does not have "daylight saving time", while CDT does. (In answers to comments you said your time zone is CST; I strongly doubt that, it is very likely CDT, meaning - affected by daylight saving time.)

Comment: Another solution would be `to_timestamp_TZ('05182021221504 UTC','MMDDYYYYHH24MISS TZR')`, if suitable.